# Squid cache 302 responses

Tags: cache, squid, http-proxy

I have a very specific use case in which I need to cache **EVERYTHING**. Including 302s. I know it's technically against the HTTP RFC, but I know those redirects will always be the same and I need them to never be retransmitted more than once.

Is there any way to make squid cache 302 responses?